# Get generic interface extension

Tags: typescript, types, set-theory

Consider the following interfaces:

```
interface A {
   name: string;
   value: number;
   sub: {
       query: number[]
   },
   old: number;
}

interface B {
   name: string;
   value: string;
   sub: {
       query: string[]
   },
   new: boolean;
}
```

I looking for a generic solution to get the interface/type:

```
interface C extends B, A {
}
```

Where C would be like the interface D:

```
interface D {
   name: string;
   value: string;
   sub: {
       query: string[]
   },
   old: number;
   new: boolean;
}
```

So I could have a function:

```
function merge<T, U>(t: T, u: U): interface C extends T, U {
  // Merge objects
  // ...
  return obj;
}
```

It doesn't have to be an interface. A type would do it also (I think).

The type `A & B` does not work because then I have an intersection (e.g. the `value` would be of type `number & string`).

Comment: Apart from the Intersection type, there is another advanced type - Union Type, that can accept values that is either number or string. More documentation here - http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Wouldn't `A | B` union do what you want?

Comment: No. A | B is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
type MergeRightBiased<TLeft, TRight> =
  TLeft extends any[] ? TRight :
    TRight extends any[] ? TRight :
      TLeft extends object ?
        TRight extends object ? {
          // All properties of Left and Right, recursive
          [P in keyof TLeft & keyof TRight]: MergeRightBiased<TLeft[P], TRight[P]>
        } & {
          // All properties of Left not in Right
          [P in Exclude<keyof TLeft, keyof TRight>]: TLeft[P];
        } & {
          // All properties of Right not in Left
          [P in Exclude<keyof TRight, keyof TLeft>]: TRight[P]
        }
          // Prefer Right
          : TRight
        : TRight;
```

Thank you @Oblosys for your help!

Comment: Ah yes, that's an interesting solution! It's a bit dodgy if something is an object only on the right-hand side (e.g. `Merge<{o:42},{o:{p:1}}>`), but an extra condition on `T` could fix that. And I'd expect the more symmetrical `[P in Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>]: U[P]` instead of `U`, but I guess this works due to the right bias. (by the way @username pings only work in comments)

Answer (score 1):

I use this `MergeReplace` type for more accurately typing things like `Object.assign({}, T, S)`:

```
type MergeReplace<T, S> = Omit<T, keyof T & keyof S> & S;
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

If you're using TypeScript < 2.8, `Exclude` can be defined like this:

```
type Project<K extends string, T> = (T & {[x: string]: never})[K];
type Delete<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P} & {[P in U]: never});
type Exclude<T extends string, U extends string> = Project<T, Delete<T,U>>;
```

[TypeScript playground with examples](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Sound%20typings%20for%20pure%20Object.assign%20(e.g.%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20..%20))%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20MergeReplace%3CT%2C%20S%3E%20%3D%20Omit%3CT%2C%20keyof%20T%20%26%20keyof%20S%3E%20%26%20S%3B%0D%0Atype%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Exclude%20before%20TypeScript%202.8%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20Exclude%3CT%20extends%20string%2C%20U%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20Project%3CT%2C%20Delete%3CT%2CU%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20Project%3CK%20extends%20string%2C%20T%3E%20%3D%20(T%20%26%20%7B%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20never%7D)%5BK%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20Delete%3CT%20extends%20string%2C%20U%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20(%7B%5BP%20in%20T%5D%3A%20P%7D%20%26%20%7B%5BP%20in%20U%5D%3A%20never%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20global%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20interface%20ObjectConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20soundAssign%3CU%2C%20V%3E(target%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20source1%3A%20U%2C%20source2%3A%20V)%3A%20MergeReplace%3CU%2C%20V%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20soundAssign%3CU%2C%20V%2C%20W%3E(target%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20source1%3A%20U%2C%20source2%3A%20V%2C%20source3%20%3A%20W)%3A%20MergeReplace%3CMergeReplace%3CU%2C%20V%3E%2CW%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20For%20more%20type%20parameters%2C%20just%20add%20left-associative%20MergeReplace%20applications%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AObject.soundAssign%20%3D%20Object.assign%3B%20%2F%2F%20nasty%20prototype%20assignment%20to%20show%20both%20assign%20flavors%20in%20a%20single%20module.%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test1%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20unsoundAssign%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%20'I%20will%20be%20overwritten'%7D%2C%20%7Bb%3A%20true%2C%20c%3A%20false%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20unsoundAssign%3A%20%7Ba%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20string%7D%20%26%20%7Bb%3A%20boolean%2C%20c%3A%20boolean%7D%0D%0A%20%20const%20unsoundTest%20%3D%20unsoundAssign.b%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20INCORRECT%3A%20unsoundTest%3A%20(string%20%26%20true)%20%7C%20(string%20%26%20false)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20soundAssign%20%3D%20Object.soundAssign(%7B%7D%2C%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%20'I%20will%20be%20overwritten'%7D%2C%20%7Bb%3A%20true%2C%20c%3A%20false%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20soundAssign%3A%20MergeReplace%3C%7Ba%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20string%7D%2C%20%7Bb%3A%20boolean%2C%20c%3A%20boolean%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20const%20soundTest%20%3D%20soundAssign.b%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20CORRECT%3A%20soundTest%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20unsoundAssign%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20%7Bp%3A%20%7Bmissing%3A%20'x'%2C%20present%3A%201%7D%7D%2C%20%7Bp%3A%20%7Bpresent%3A%20'still%20here'%7D%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20unsoundAssign%3A%20%7Bp%3A%20%7Bmissing%3A%20string%2C%20present%3A%20number%7D%7D%20%26%20%7Bp%3A%20%7B%20present%3A%20string%20%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20const%20unsoundTest1%20%3D%20unsoundAssign.p.missing%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20INCORRECT%3A%20unsoundTest1%3A%20string%20(should%20be%20rejected)%0D%0A%20%20const%20unsoundTest2%20%3D%20unsoundAssign.p.present%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20INCORRECT%3A%20unsoundTest2%3A%20number%20%26%20string%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20soundAssign%20%3D%20Object.soundAssign(%7B%7D%2C%20%7Bp%3A%20%7Bmissing%3A%20'x'%2C%20present%3A%201%7D%7D%2C%20%7Bp%3A%20%7Bpresent%3A%20'still%20here'%7D%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20soundAssign%3A%20MergeReplace%3C%7Bp%3A%20%7Bmissing%3A%20string%2C%20present%3A%20number%7D%7D%2C%20%7Bp%3A%20%7B%20present%3A%20string%20%7D%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20const%20soundTest1%20%3D%20soundAssign.p.missing%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20CORRECT%3A%20rejected%20with%20%22Property%20'missing'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'%7B%20present%3A%20string%3B%20%7D'%22%0D%0A%20%20const%20soundTest2%20%3D%20soundAssign.p.present%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20CORRECT%3A%20soundTest2%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Note that `MergeReplace` is right biased, so if `T` and `S` share a property but with different types, the type from `S` is chosen.

Check out [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-311923766) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. This is the right direction. But it does not support nested objects.

Comment: No it won't, it will just take the rightmost one. I think it's going to be tricky to support merging nested object types without creating intersection types for differently typed properties like your `value`, but maybe there's a clever solution.